# Using mod_rewrite to extract request headers before authentication

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-perl

I need to rewrite a URL to copy an authentication token from the URL into a header (because a new client can't use headers), and remove the (large) token from the URL.

```
<Location /foo/>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/(authtoken)/([^/]*)(.*)$ $1$4 [E=HAS_auth:$3,L]
  RequestHeader set AUTHTOKEN %{HAS_auth}e env=HAS_auth
  SetHandler perl-script
  PerlAccessHandler AuthHandler
```

So a request of the form "/foo/boo/moo/authtoken/baaaaaa/bar" is rewritten as "/foo/boo/moo/bar" and a request header "AUTHTOKEN: baaaaaa" added to the request.

The URI is being rewritten, and the test env var is being set, but the access handler (mod_perl) does not see the AUTHTOKEN header, or even ENV{HAS_auth} although the rewrite is working (I logged it).

Is it possible to actually to rewrite and set headers before the authentication(access) handler, and if so, how?

Comment: I’d assume authentication happens before rewriting … because getting a resource rewritten that the client would not even be allowed to access in the first place would make not a lot of sense in most cases, I suppose.

Comment: That's not my understand of the processing cycle. Normally if you want rewrites based on authn you need special directives (LA-U). https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/tech.html

Comment: I've ended up with a mod_perl solution using a PerlTransHandler to manipulate the uri and headers. It would be still be good to know if it can be done with mod_rewrite and mod_headers.